# What is the Stash GIT API for a branch name that contains slash in it?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

For example, I have a URL like this that works for a GET request:
`https://stash-server.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/something/repos/project/commits/develop/`

This works for the `develop` branch, but when I try to do `feature/something` to access commits on that branch, it returns 404 not found.

Documentation is lacking, I am not able to find how to access branch names like this...

Thanks!

Comment: What git command are you trying to run?

Comment: This is a REST GET API request, not via git client.

Comment: Slashes are perfectly fine in branch names. The problem seems to be outside of git.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Well I double checked and triple checked, I did not mispell the branch name. I still get a 404 with XML message saying `null for uri: ...` If I were to replace branch with `feature-something`, then it says commit does not exist in repository... So obviously your reply is wrong

Comment: Obviously? No. Slashes **are** perfectly fine in branch names for all purposes. The use case you're describing involves many other steps, like network / http request / Rest API / browser / others. "404 not found" is *not* a git error. That's what I meant by "outside of git". If you create a `feature-something` branch, it has nothing to do with your `feature/something` branch *per se*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution/workaround, was to perform two REST calls, the first one to the `/branches` endpoint, iterate over the results to find the correct branch, and get the `latestCommit` hash, then make a REST call to `commits/hashID` - this works around this issue of no way to access branch names like `feature/something` directly via REST API.